Is it possible to configure Git to load an additional config file based on the CWD?
I use Git 2.45.0. I have added the includeIf.gitdir configuration (e.g. includeIf.gitdir:/some/path/.path=/some/path/.gitconfig). It works as expected when the current working directory contains a .git folder, however, it does not wot when the CWD does not contain one, it fails to load the additional config. It can be demonstrated using git clone in such a folder in the includeIf path that does not have a .git subfolder.
Is there a way to fix this? I want to use the additional config even when there is no .git folder in the CWD?
Example config in ~/.gitconfig:
[includeIf "gitdir:~/some/path/"]
  path = ~/some.gitconfig

As I understand it based on the docs, gitdir keyword always checks for the .git folder existance, never just for the CWD.

Update
I want to clone a repo via SSH, however, I cannot make it work.
# This works, but it requires me to type in my credentials
git clone https://git.example.com/path/repo.git

# This fails, as it does not recognises my additional config
git clone git@git.example.com:path/repo.git

# Likewise, this fails too, although I have no idea why
git clone \
  -c "user.name=$(git config --file ~/some/path/.gitconfig --get user.name)" \
  -c "user.email=$(git config --file ~/some/path/.gitconfig --get user.email)" \
  git@git.example.com:path/repo.git

As it it not possible to add an includeIf config that would consider the CWD in Git 2.45.0, how to make it work using some -c/--config CLI options?
Note that I use a single Git user on the git.example.com server.

includeIf.gitdir is about .git dir. The docs is very clear about it. There is nothing to fix, everything work as designed.

That is how I understood the docs. Unfortunately, it does not help me much.

Why are you trying to set user.name/user.email for git clone? To authenticate? That wouldn't work. user.name/user.email are not authorization credentials. They're commit identification data. They're used during commit creation and never used during clone/fetch/pull/push. Logins/passwords, access tokens, SSH keypairs are authorization credentials.

Well, as git clone has thrown an error that it could not read from the remote repo, I have tried to add those config vars (based on this). However, I have just realised that cloning a different, older repo from the same Git server works as expected, however, I cannot clone a repo I created on the same server today. Thus, this seems to be an issue of the remote Git server and not the local Git client.

Then my advice is to delete the question as it's wrong on all accounts.

That is one way to deal with this situation. Another way is create a feature request on Git repo to add something like includeIf.cwddir. IMHO the (original) question is still valid, although there is no solution yet. It might be useful for others facing the same issue, as includeIf.gitdir obviously does not work for cloning, although it is not related to the actual issue I face. … Do you still think I should delete the question?

That's up to you. Nobody would provide a real answer here, maybe someone just repeat the docs.

common ways to handle authentication: a. use a credentials manager, b. for ssh: add a Host  section in your .ssh/config and set the settings you want (username, key_file to use) there

it looks like your question is about passing credentials through ssh when cloning, the linked answer describes that. If it turns out to not be your question, please add a comment or edit your question
